# How to access same-named functions from multiple modules dynamically?

Tags: python

I have a project structured this way:

```
├── main.py
└── scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── script1.py
    ├── script2.py
    ├── script3.py
    ├──     .
    ├──     .
    ├──     .
    └── script30.py
```

Each `script{i}.py` consists of exactly one function `foo`. What I would like to achieve is a dict of those foos along with corresponding module names in `main.py`:

```
result = {'script1': scripts.script1.foo, ..., 'scripts30': scripts.script30.foo}
```

What I would also love to achieve is

1. doing it without importing `script{i}` for each `i`
2. a nice and clean code
3. not writing names of those modules explicitly, especially inside `main.py` (number of modules in `scripts` can grow in future, it would be annoying to have to update `main.py` every time it happens).

Is this even possible? All my approaches resulted in pure ugliness.
Suggestions of restructuring my project are also welcome.

Comment: Suggestions for how to restructure the project are difficult to come up with without knowing some context about why you've structured it this way to begin with. (I am curious.)

Answer (score 0):

A package's `__init__.py` script can do things such as importing the modules in the package directory.

This means you could do something like this:

`__int__.py`:

```
import types as _types


def import_package_functions_named(funcname):
    """ Dynamically imports all modules in this package directory and creates a
        dictionary mapping the module's name to the target function if it exists.
    """
    import traceback
    import os
    globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()

    registry = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(__name__):
        # Process all python files in directory that don't start with an underscore
        # (this also prevents this module from importing itself).
        if filename[0] != '_' and filename.split('.')[-1] in ('py', 'pyw'):
            modulename = filename.split('.')[0]  # Filename sans extension.
            package_module = '.'.join([__name__, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(package_module, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                raise

            match = module.__dict__.get(funcname)
            if isinstance(match, _types.FunctionType):  # Ensure it's a function.
                registry[modulename] = match

    return registry
```

Which would allow you to get the result you want in the `main.py` script thusly:

```
import scripts

result = scripts.import_package_functions_named("foo")
print(result)
```

Sample output:

```
{'script1': <function foo at 0x027B30B8>, 'script2': <function foo at 0x027B33D0>, 'script3': <function foo at 0x027B3418>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a basic usage of stdlib [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages), actually very similar to the documented use case they have shown for dynamic discovery of modules.

Here it is adapted to your example project:

```
import importlib
import pkgutil
import scripts

submods = pkgutil.walk_packages(scripts.__path__, scripts.__name__ + ".")
result = {m.name: importlib.import_module(m.name).foo for m in submods}
```

> Suggestions of restructuring my project are also welcome.

Perhaps, your project is better suited to using [entry-points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/). Each submodule could register their `foo` as an entrypoint in a named group, and then you can iterate them with setuptools' [`iter_entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) or the higher level APIs in [`entrypoints`](https://entrypoints.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#high-level-api).